# Custom button bar in React-admin v4.0

Tags: react-admin

I am trying to customize the user management page using <Admin> and <Resource> and am using React-Admin v.4.0. I need to add a bar with tabs below displayed resources (4 categories of users).
Whenever a tab is selected - "Not found" error is displayed [error when selecting required tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nz0IV.png)) Although the name in the sidebar changes to the selected value and after the sidebar is clicked the whole dashboard is re-rendered to display the requested category of users, like here: [page after the sidebar is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SESk9.png)

I am trying to figure out if this is a React render related issue or something is missing in my react-admin part of the code. Without the custom bar and with a default appBar the page is working correctly.

My code looks like this:

```
   import {UserList} from 'components/UserList';

    const MyLayout_1 = ({ children }) => {
        return (
          <Layout appBar={ () => <></>} >
            {children}
            <h2>{heading}</h2>
            <MyTabBar />
          </Layout>
        );
      };
      
    return (

    <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider} layout={MyLayout_1}> 

      {selectedTab === 'users' && (
        <Resource name="users" list={UserList} />
      )}
      {selectedTab === 'approved' && (
        <Resource name="approved" list={UserList} />
      )}
      {selectedTab === 'pending' && (
        <Resource name="pending" list={UserList} />
      )}
      {selectedTab === 'declined' && (
        <Resource name="declined" list={UserList} />
      )}
    </Admin>
      );
```

I tried to add customRoutes to  with Resources required for each route, but no success.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way you should customize the side menu in React Admin. The `Resources` the user has access to should always be available as children of `<Admin>`.

Rather, you should follow the [Using a Custom Menu](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Theming.html#using-a-custom-menu) doc to customize the way your side menu looks, and add the tab logic in there.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out @slax57 
I'll try to customize the side menu, now it makes more sense